# Is there a way in a try/except loop to parse list entries with exception errors into a new list?

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm learning python and I've been working on a script to perform actions towards a list of devices, where more than one type of credential is needed. I'm trying to find the best way to deal with failed connections to the devices. The list is just an IP address on each line. One of my ideas is to just make a for loop

```
for ip in iplist:
    try:
        perform_some_action()
    except authenticationfailure:
        perform_some_action_on_failed_authentications()
```

First question, does the except function have a built in way I can use to parse the failed list entry?

Second question, would I actually be better off running through the entire list in one for loop, create a new "list2", remove successful devices from "list2" and then create another for loop running through "list2"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In the `except` clause you do have access to `ip`. Is that what you are asking? Without more context, it isn't very clear just what your question is.

Comment: What exactly do `perform_some_action` and `perform_some_action_on_failed_authentications` do? (Aside from the obvious fact that  `perform_some_action` can raise `authenticationfailure`.)

Comment: What do you want to do? create a list of successful devices or you just want to perform some kinda of actions?

Comment: I run through the list using one set of credentials, but I know a lot of the connections will fail due to incorrect credentials. I want to get the IP addresses from the list, where the credentials failed and then attempt to connect using another set of credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is #2 -- create an empty container of failed connections. As connections fail, add the `ip` in the `except`. You most certainly could pass the `authenticationfailure`'s to a different function (commented out below):

```py
failed_connections = []
for ip in iplist:
    try:
        perform_some_action(ip)
    except authenticationfailure:
        failed_connections.append(ip)
        // perform_some_action_on_failed_authentications(ip)
```

I'd need to see more of your code to offer other suggestions

Comment: I tested this and it works the way I want. I just needed to understand the python logic this.